# Make a histogram of dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

Why can't I do this?

```
pandas.DataFrame([1])
```

> ```
> |   | 0 |
> ---------
> | 0 | 1 |
> ```

```
pandas.DataFrame([1]).dtypes
```

> ```
> | 0     | int64  |
> ------------------
> | dtype | object |
> ```

```
pandas.DataFrame([1]).dtypes.hist()
```

> TypeError: data type not understood

I was hoping to get a histogram of `dtypes`.

Comment: Theoretically, you cannot plot a histogram of a categorical variable. Practically, the values in your Series are strings so they cannot be aggregated like numbers. What exactly are you trying to do? Can it be a bar chart where you have the dtypes on the x-axis and the total number of occurrences on the y axis? If so, try `df.get_dtype_counts().plot.bar()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need a bar plot as a histogram of non numeric Series is not well defined as commented by @ayhan; You can do a value counts of the `dtypes` and then plot it as bars:

```
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1.0,'a']]).dtypes.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works great! Also I just found `prop.dtypes.value_counts()`